# Overriding page_list controller inside a package in Concrete5.6.1.2

Tags: concrete5

Is there a way to override the controller file located at `/concrete/blocks/page_list/controller.php` and place it inside `/packages/mypackage/blocks/page_list/`? I'd like to make some changes to the original edit and view.

In `/packages/mypackage/blocks/page_list/controller.php`, I tried doing this but it does not seem to have any effect:

`class PageListBlockController extends Concrete5_Controller_Block_PageList { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You can now override/extend core classes via packages in newer versions Concrete5 (v.5.6+).

You must add to your package's main controller.php file:

```
public function on_start(){
    $objEnv = Environment::get();
    $objEnv->overrideCoreByPackage('blocks/page_list/controller.php', $this);
}
```

You don't have to copy over the whole core controller, just declare your new block controller like this:

```
class PageList extends Concrete5_Controller_Block_Page_List {
    public function mymethod() {
    }
}
```

(what class you're extending and where you put the file may vary depending on your C5 version - just compare the `/concrete/` folder structure and files for reference)

The following C5 forum posts may be of help:

[Overriding Core Class with Package](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/overriding-core-class-via-a-package/#424220)

[Can A Package Override A Core Library?](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/can-a-package-override-a-core-library/)

A caution, though - if you're hoping to submit to the official C5 marketplace, they generally don't accept Add-Ons with overrides.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't override a block controller from within a package. Just imagine if more than one package did this. (You can, however, have a block template within your package directory, but this makes sense because it adds rather than replaces.)

If you can, you should override by putting it in `/blocks/page_list/controller.php`.

However, if you still need to override it from you package, you should look into the not-very-well-supported `Environment::overrideCoreByPackage()` and try:

```
Environment::get()->overrideCoreByPackage('/blocks/page_list/controller.php', $myPackage);
```

See the source:
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/libraries/environment.php#L123

And an example of usage:
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/override-a-core-class-within-a-package/#460765